# How can I create an anchor that has circular corners?

Tags: html, css

[image]

The Anchor I'm referring to is above

I understand how to create an with rounded corners with border-raidus, however not like the anchor above.

Comment: `border-radius` is the way to do it. What's the *specific* problem?

Comment: Show what you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use `border-radius`. 
But the catch is not to use percentages but use half the height of the element in `px` or another unit like `em` or `rem`.

Here's some example code that could help you.

```css
.anchor {
    width: 120px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 25px;

    background: red;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="anchor">Contact</div>
```

Comment: thankyou this works, I was using percentages rather than pixels